# Implementing snapshot functionality for latency demanding program

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, shared-memory, low-latency

We are developing program, that works on data located in shared memory. Program is latency demanding and processes huge amount of data.

If program fails, we must return to last working state FAST.

One way is to read and process data from transaction log, which contains transactions from the start of the day. But this is not fast at all, considering size of transaction log (hundreds of gigabytes).

We are now looking the way to create snapshots of data that can be written to disk and read very fast if program fails. But snapshot creation must not lock program execution and data in that snapshot must be consistent.

If we were using local memory for keeping data instead of shared memory, solution will be easy:

1. fork()
2. write data to disk

Because of copy-on-write on linux, only changed data will be copied, so it is very fast.

But we are using posix shared memory.

Is there any way to do it with speed and consistency in mind?

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare enough CPU cycles for a memcpy(), you could:

1. fork()
2. lock shared memory
3. memcpy (shared_mem -> some_buffer)
4. unlock shared memory
5. write data to disk taking the time you like

Comment: Right now shared memory have size of 15-30 GB. So, no, memcpy will take too much time and memory.